# dbup AzureDatabaseEdition

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, dbup

i am getting an error in dbup on:

```
EnsureDatabase.For.SqlDatabase(connectionString, 300, AzureDatabaseEdition.Basic);
```

Error is:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near 'basic'.'

thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

As per official document you don’t need to mention the azure database edition as parameter just pass connection string as parameter and it will check if the target database exists if not it will create database for you

```
EnsureDatabase.For.SqlDatabase(connectionString);
```

Reference: https://dbup.readthedocs.io/en/latest/